# Executing Python script without hanging terminal

Tags: python

Now this question might seem like an questions like [this](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbuMmw653QAhWEF5QKHW0tBZ4QFgglMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F396654%2Fhow-to-run-the-python-program-in-the-background-in-ubuntu-machine&usg=AFQjCNEpIStKjgu2KHiHDgk0x2AkS9WkWQ&sig2=KD4t8A_V2zWYPgYuBLTctQ) one and [this](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbuMmw653QAhWEF5QKHW0tBZ4QFggtMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2975624%2Fhow-to-run-a-python-script-in-the-background-even-after-i-logout-ssh&usg=AFQjCNE4aOXuuBkcIqGpFtKS_W3TUj0fDA&sig2=DZ89OsEvxezgTtnzajBThQ) one.

However unfortunately the above solutions don't work for me. I need a way to execute a Python 3.4.3 script, leave it running when the terminal closes, and have it not hang in terminal and executed directly.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html/mysite/scripts $ nohup python3 my.script.py &
```

The above runs the script, but it hangs in terminal, I cannot enter any other commands until I stop it, by pressing `CTRL + C`.

Is there a way to achieve something like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html/mysite/scripts $ nohup python3 my.script.py &
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html/mysite/scripts $ 
(Now I enter more commands, despite the script still running)
```

I hope I have provided enough information, hopefully you can help me, thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're just missing the ampersand. `nohup python3 my.script.py&`

Comment: With the ampersand, the script should run in the background. I'm not sure what more to tell you. Maybe copy/paste the exact command you executed? And tell us how you've determined that it's "hanging" the terminal?

Comment: `www-data@raspberrypi:~/html/mysite/scripts $ nohup python3 my.script.py &`

Comment: Your script is really called `my.script.py`? I asked for an exact copy/paste because your initial post had the same line and was missing the ampersand, which would cause the issue you saw. "Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence." You're claiming that the ampersand doesn't cause the command to be executed in the background, so you're going to have to be very convincing with your evidence.

Comment: In this case, it actually is called that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a quick google search, I found

```
start /b python3 my.script.py
```

for windows or

```
python3 my.script.py &
```

on lunix (bash).

Comment: I ended up fixing it with `python3 myscript.py 1 > /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

If the ampersand doesn't work, you can use a terminal multiplexer like [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) or [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) for your purpose.

Comment: I ended up fixing it with `python3 myscript.py 1 > /dev/null`